# Linfu dynamic proxy and Interface methods that return IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, interface, ienumerable, linfu-dynamicproxy

I am using Linfu to generate a proxy object for an interface. Everything works fine except when calling a method that returns an `IEnumerable<object>` I get an error something like this:

> Unable to cast object of type '< IEnumerableRpcCall >d__2' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'.

FYI: `IEnumerableRpcCall` is the name of the method inside the interceptor code that does `yield return object` rather than `return object`.

It seems the problem is that linfu is returning a pointer to the method rather than an `IEnumerable`. Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to casting up from `IEnumerable< object >` to `IEnumerable< string >` (or whatever type). I solved it by wrapping my enumerator logic inside a custom class that implements `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
  public class MyEnumerator<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
  {
        // custom logic here
  }
```

and then in my interceptor code I use reflection to instantiate the correct generic type as specified in the InvocationInfo object:

```
  private class MyLinfuInterceptor : IInterceptor
  {
      public object Intercept(InvocationInfo info)
      {
            MethodInfo methodBeingRequested = info.TargetMethod;
            // enumerable return type
            if (methodBeingRequested.ReturnType.IsGenericType
               && methodBeingRequested.ReturnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)
               && methodBeingRequested.ReturnType.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1)
            {
               Type constructedEnumerator = typeof(MyEnumerator<>).MakeGenericType(methodBeingRequested.ReturnType.GetGenericArguments());
               var result = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedEnumerator);

               return result;
            }

            // code to handle other return types here...
       }
   }
```

And now the proxy object for my interface no longer throws an invalid cast exception when I make method calls that return `IEnumerable<>`

([more on writing LinFu Dynamic Proxy interceptors here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20884/Introducing-the-LinFu-Framework-Part-I-LinFu-Dynam))